# sed with line numbers as variables

Tags: unix, sed

I want to get specific lines using `sed`, where the first line and the last line to get are stored in variables.

Here is an example, I want to get all the lines between the first line (here line number 5) and the last line (here number 8), and then I use grep to search a specific word.

```
firstLine=5
lastLine=8

sedResult="$(sed -n "$firstLine,$lastLine p" text.txt | grep word -aIi)"
```

But I am having errors. The errors look like this :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unexpected `,'
```

what is the proper way to use variables as line numbers ?

Comment: What error do you have? It works for me.

Comment: I will edit my post. In fact, I am using sed with grep, so the error might be caused by that.

Comment: It still works for me.

Comment: Nevermind, it works for me too now. I don't know what I did to fix it, but it was probably a problem with quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial expression has broken *double quotes usage*. It should be:

```
firstLine=5
lastLine=8
sedResult=$(sed -n "$firstLine,$lastLine p" text.txt)
```